# PyQt5 Call another class and open new window after button pressed

Tags: python, class, pyqt5, window

I have made a GUI using PyQt5. What I need, and don't know how to do it, is that after clicking on button in my main GUI should appear a new window with dataframe. I have both "windows" in separate classes and I dont know, how to connect them together.

Here is my main Window:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    .
    .
    .
    self.X_pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.New_tab)
    self.X_pushButton.clicked.connect(**Here I want to call the second Window**)
    self.gridLayout_10.addWidget(self.X_pushButton, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    .
    .
    .

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here is the second window I want to open by clicking on the push button:

```
data = pd.read_csv("My_data.csv",index_col=0)

class pandasModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self._data = data
    
    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[0]
    
    def columnCount(self, parnet=None):
        return self._data.shape[1]
    
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])
        return None
    
    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[col]
        return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    model = pandasModel(Data)
    view = QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.resize(800, 600)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you very much for your help. :)

Comment: Right now you have the second window file written as if it is supposed to be a standalone script.  It also appears that you are editing a uic file which is always discouraged.

Comment: Please read the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to understand how to properly use pyuic files. Editing those files (just like trying to mimic their behavior, or merge the contents of those files) is always discouraged for *a lot* of reasons. Those files are *always* meant to be imported, and those classes are intended to be used for multiple inheritance or composition.